# How to Modify List of Records in entityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using Entity Framework,I need to Retreive A List Of Entities Then Manipulate This List Based On Some Conitions, then Save The Final List to Context.
Like This:

```
    Sample
    {
      int id;
      int value;
    }
var sampleList=db.samples.toList();
//Add some records to sampleList
sampleList.Add(new sample(){value = 10});
//Change the Value of Some Records in sampleList
sampleList[0].value= 5 ;
db.savechanges()
```

**Added Records to List Are not Tracked And Inserted To DB ,But Changed Values Are Updated.**
Strange Behavior Of EF!! Any Explanation???
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your Add to list code too?

Comment: Nothing is saved because you have not added anything to your context. You are missing db.samples.add("sample object") which notifies ef change tracker to add this to your context. Then db.savechanges() to save it to your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, base on your script, what should've been done is something like this.

```
//var sampleList=db.samples.toList();
//Add some records to sampleList
Sample sampInsertObject = new sample() { value = 10 };
db.samples.Add(sampInsertObject);
db.SaveChanges(); // execute save so that context will execute "INSERT"

/* 
 EF also executes SCOPE_IDENTITY() after insert to retrieve the
 PrimaryKey value from the database to sampInsertObject.
*/

// Change the Value of Some Records in sampleList

var sampUpdateList = db.samples.ToList();
if(sampUpdateList.Count != 0)
{
    // Get specific object from sample list
    Sample sampUpdateObject = sampUpdateList.ToList()[0];
    sampUpdateObject.Value = 5;
    db.SaveChanges(); // execute save so that context will execute "UPDATE"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me first answer the easier question of why your new records were not saved.  You cannot just modify the objects and call save changes, you need to either Add or Update the DataBase.

```
db.Add(sample); // If sample does not exist
db.Update(sample); //If sample already exists and you are updating it
db.SaveChanges();
```

As for modifying the list and saving that to context.  I believe you will have to iterate over the list itself and Add, Delete, Update each Sample Object in it.

Comment: Of Course I dont want to directly Add records to context, because i dont know which record is new and should be added and which one should be Updated, also we can update values in case of Question,problem is with Add.

Comment: If you can't figure out which entites are new yourself, how do you think EF will be able to do it? A normally quite easy way to do it is to see if the Id is set.

Besides it wouldn't work if you could add items to a normal List and it would save. That would create chaos.

Comment: Because All The Job is Done Inside a Function,And I didnt want the Function Itself to access DbContext, But It seems There is no other Choice